# How to include a full R distribution in my GitHub repository

Tags: r, github

I build transport models for various government agencies. My model is managed through GitHub, and it depends on R to perform certain calculations. I currently have my *entire* r installation folder in the repository. This can't be the right solution, but here are some of my constraints:

- My clients are usually even less sophisticated programmers then I am. When they download/clone the model, it just needs to work.
- This needs to be the case 10 years from now - regardless of what the current build of R and all the package dependencies are.

Placing my entire R folder in the repo solves these two problems, but creates some new ones:

- The repository is much larger than it needs to be / longer download time.
- If the transport model is updated to a new version (say v2.0), I'd want to update R and its packages to the latest versions. I'm afraid this would increase the size of the repo even further.

One solution I understand is submodules. I could place the full R folder in a separate repo and bring it in as a submodule. This, at the very least, cleans up the model repository.

What about zipping the R folder? Some early testing showed that git can diff the zip file, but I don't know if it is doing it as a flat file or reading the contents. Also, is GitHub going to complain about 100MB+ zip file? I'd like to avoid GitLFS if I can, but asking my clients to unzip that file wouldn't be a problem.

I also looked at packrat, but as far as I can tell, that only works for R projects.

Lastly, I don't entirely understand makefiles / recipes, but it would be nice if there was a script I could run that would download specific versions of R and it's libraries. One complicating thing is that some of the R packages are private GitHub repos.

Anyway, I'm happy to provide more info if needed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [This discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/enabling-reproducible-research-amp-R-package-management-amp-install-package-version-amp-BiocLite-td4660277.html) looks like it could be useful for you.